# Graphics.DrawString() vs TextRenderer.DrawText()

Tags: c#, drawstring

I am confused about these two methods.

My understanding is that Graphics.DrawString() uses GDI+ and is a graphics-based implementation, while TextRenderer.DrawString() uses GDI and allows a large range of fonts and supports unicode.

My issue is when I attempt to print decimal-based numbers as percentages to a printer. My research leads me to believe that TextRenderer is a better way to go.

However, MSDN advises, *"The DrawText methods of TextRenderer are not supported for printing. You should always use the DrawString methods of the Graphics class."*

My code to print using Graphics.DrawString is:

```
if (value != 0)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Format("{0:0.0%}", value), GetFont("Arial", 12, "Regular"), GetBrush("Black"), HorizontalOffset + X, VerticleOffset + Y);
```

This prints "100%" for number between 0 and 1 and "-100% for numbers below zero.

When I place,

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.0%}", value));
```

inside my print method, the value prints in the correct format (eg: 75.0%), so I am pretty sure the  problem lies within Graphics.DrawString().

Comment: Seems a bit odd. DrawString shouldn't be aware of any sort of formatting since String.Format simply returns a string. You might want to try a couple things: - In visual studio, break on the e.Graphics line, highlight the String.Format() parameter and hit Shift-F9 to see what is returned.  Or put a literal in place of the format temporarily (i.e. "100.0%") to see if DrawString treats it differently.

Comment: This behavior sounds like `value` is being treated as an integer. I'd suggest breaking out your String.Format into a separate string variable so that you can set a breakpoint on the Graphics.DrawString and examine the contents of value and the resulting string during debugging. I seriously doubt this is Graphics.DrawString doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This does not appear to have anything to do with `Graphics.DrawString` or `TextRenderer.DrawString` or `Console.Writeline`.

The format specifier you are providing, `{0.0%}`, does not simply append a percentage sign.  As per the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPct), the `%` custom specifier ...

> causes a number to be multiplied by 100 before it is formatted.

In my tests, both `Graphics.DrawString` and `Console.WriteLine` exhibit the same behavior when passed the same value and format specifier.

`Console.WriteLine` test:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double value = .5;
        var fv = string.Format("{0:0.0%}", value);
        Console.WriteLine(fv);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`Graphics.DrawString` Test:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PictureBox box = new PictureBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        box.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        box.BackColor = Color.White;

        box.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(DrawTest);
        this.Controls.Add(box);
    }

    public void DrawTest(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        double value = .5;
        var fs = string.Format("{0:0.0%}", value);
        var font = new Font("Arial", 12);
        var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        var point = new PointF(100.0F, 100.0F);

        g.DrawString(fs, font, brush, point);
    }
}
```