# Graphics.DrawString vs TextRenderer.DrawText?Which can Deliver Better Quality

Tags: c#, .net, text, gdi+, gdi

TextRenderer is based on GDI and Graphics.DrawString  is based on GDI+.Which of these functions can deliver better quality text while drawing text on an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799646/graphics-drawstring-vs-textrenderer-drawtext?

Comment: @minitech The Question is a Bit different and moreover its unresolved

Comment: If this one is closed as a duplicate, the point is that answers will go to that one... moreover, no-one's answered this.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

i'm going to cross-post my answer from over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404811/12597), just so that the information gets around.

---

There are two ways of drawing text in .NET:

- **GDI+**: `graphics.MeasureString` and `graphics.DrawString`
- **GDI**: `TextRenderer.MeasureText` and `TextRenderer.DrawText`

In .NET 1.1 everything used **GDI+** for text rendering. [But there were some problems:](http://www.siao2.com/2005/06/27/432986.aspx)

> - There are some performance issues caused by the somewhat stateless nature of GDI+, where device contexts would be set and then the original restored after each call.
> - The shaping engines for international text have been updated many times for Windows/Uniscribe and for Avalon (Windows Presentation Foundation), but have not been updated for GDI+, which causes international rendering support for new languages to not have the same level of quality.

So they knew they wanted to change the .NET framework to stop using **GDI+**'s text rendering system, and use **GDI**. At first they hoped they could simply change:

```
graphics.DrawString
```

to call the old `DrawText` API, instead of GDI+. But [they couldn't make the text-wrapping and spacing match exactly as what GDI+ did](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/10/13/480632.aspx).

> In Windows Forms 2.0, we added support for drawing GDI text.  At first we had grandiose plans of poking and prodding at the DrawText API such that we could make it match up exactly how GDI+'s DrawString API works.  I actually think we got pretty close, but there are fundamental differences in word wrapping and character spacing that as mere consumers of the both APIs, Windows Forms could not solve.
>
> So now we're presented with a problem: we want to switch everyone over to the new TextRenderer APIs so text will look better, localize better, draw more consistently with other dialogs in the operating system...  ...but we dont want to break folks counting on GDI+ measure string for calculations of where their text should line up.

So they were forced to keep `graphics.DrawString` to call GDI+ (compatiblity reasons; people who were calling `graphics.DrawString` would suddenly find that their text didn't wrap the way it used to). [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usecompatibletextrendering(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The GDI based [TextRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx) class was introduced in the .NET Framework 2.0 to improve performance, make text look better, and improve support for international fonts. In earlier versions of the .NET Framework, the GDI+ based [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) class was used to perform all text rendering. GDI calculates character spacing and word wrapping differently from GDI+. In a Windows Forms application that uses the [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) class to render text, this could cause the text for controls that use [TextRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx) to appear different from the other text in the application. To resolve this incompatibility, you can set the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property to **true** for a specific control. To set `UseCompatibleTextRendering` to **true** for all supported controls in the application, call the [Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault(v=vs.110).aspx) method with a parameter of **true**.

A new static `TextRenderer` class was created to wrap GDI text rendering. It has two methods:

```
TextRenderer.MeasureText
TextRenderer.DrawText
```

> **Note:** `TextRenderer` is a wrapper around GDI, while `graphics.DrawString` is still a wrapper around GDI+.

---

Then there was the issue of what to do with all the existing .NET controls, e.g.:

- `Label`
- `Button`
- `TextBox`

They wanted to switch them over to use `TextRenderer` (i.e. GDI), but they had to be careful. There might be people who depended on their controls drawing like they did in .NET 1.1.

### And so was born "*compatible text rendering*"

By default, controls in application behave like they did in .NET 1.1 (they are "*compatible*").

You **turn off** compatibility mode by calling:

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

This makes your application better, faster, with better international support. To sum up:

```
SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true)  SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)
=======================================  ========================================
 default                                  opt-in
 bad                                      good
 the one we don't want to use             the one we want to use
 uses GDI+ for text rendering             uses GDI for text rendering
 graphics.MeasureString                   TextRenderer.MeasureText
 graphics.DrawString                      TextRenderer.DrawText
 Behaves same as 1.1                      Behaves *similar* to 1.1
                                          Looks better
                                          Localizes better
                                          Faster
```

---

It's also useful to note the mapping between GDI+ `TextRenderingHint` and the corresponding [`LOGFONT` Quality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) used for GDI font drawing:

```
TextRenderingHint           mapped by TextRenderer to LOGFONT quality
========================    =========================================================
ClearTypeGridFit            CLEARTYPE_QUALITY (5) (Windows XP: CLEARTYPE_NATURAL (6))
AntiAliasGridFit            ANTIALIASED_QUALITY (4)
AntiAlias                   ANTIALIASED_QUALITY (4)
SingleBitPerPixelGridFit    PROOF_QUALITY (2)
SingleBitPerPixel           DRAFT_QUALITY (1)
else (e.g.SystemDefault)    DEFAULT_QUALITY (0)
```

---

### Samples

Here's some comparisons of GDI+ (graphics.DrawString) verses GDI (TextRenderer.DrawText) text rendering:

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit`, **GDI**: `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY`:

[image]

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintAntiAlias`, **GDI**: `ANTIALIASED_QUALITY`:

[image]

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintAntiAliasGridFit`, **GDI**: *not supported, uses ANTIALIASED_QUALITY*:

[image]

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintSingleBitPerPixelGridFit`, **GDI**: `PROOF_QUALITY`:

[image]

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintSingleBitPerPixel`, **GDI**: `DRAFT_QUALITY`:

[image]

i find it odd that `DRAFT_QUALITY` is identical to `PROOF_QUALITY`, which is identical to `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY`.

**See also**

- [UseCompatibleTextRendering - Compatible with whaaaaaat?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/10/13/480632.aspx)
- [Sorting it all out: A quick look at Whidbey's TextRenderer](http://www.siao2.com/2005/06/27/432986.aspx)
- [MSDN: LOGFONT Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [AppCompat Guy: GDI vs. GDI+ Text Rendering Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/05/19/gdi-vs-gdi-text-rendering-performance.aspx)
- [GDI+ Text, Resolution Independence, and Rendering Methods.
  Or - Why does my text look different in GDI+ and in GDI?](http://windowsclient.net/articles/gdiptext.aspx)

Comment: The reason that `DRAFT_QUALITY` is identical to `PROOF_QUALITY` is because of the font you've chosen. `DRAFT_QUALITY` just means that the font mapper should prioritize the matching of the specified logical attributes over character quality when selecting a font; `PROOF_QUALITY` inverts this relationship. If the font mapper doesn't have to make a choice, then the two values will generate the same output. As for why these are both identical to `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY`, that's because you have ClearType enabled on your system (and font supports), and so both `DRAFT_QUALITY` and `PROOF_QUALITY` use it.

Comment: Not strictly related to the question, but also note that DrawString() throws `ExternalException A generic error occurred in GDI+` when used with strings over 32000 characters.  TextRenderer.DrawText() doesn't.

Comment: How do you set quality related settings for TextRenderer?

Comment: @AmirSinaMashayekh [Graphics.TextRenderingHint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: I tried it before. Unlike `Graphics.DrawString()`, `TextRenderer.DrawText()` doesn't care about properties of graphics object at all! Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63987683/10600811).

Answer (score 6):

Just my 2 cents: I always use Graphics.DrawString, *except* when I need to do custom painting for my (Windows Forms) controls. For example in a listbox that has OwnerDraw set, if I attach a DrawItem event handler that fully paints items, including item text. Or in a custom control I have to paint myself.

In an application that uses Visual Styles on an OS that supports it and has it enabled, text drawn with Graphics.DrawString looks "off" when compared to regular text drawn by other controls. This appears to be mainly because of differences in the way "ClearType" is (or is not) handled, although I am not sure and I do not have docs to back that statement up. (It sort of looks like the way text did on .Net 1.x or when switching FlatStyle from Standard to System and v.v.)

In such cases only (text painting on Winforms controls) I use TextRenderer.DrawText to make the text better blend in with the other controls.

If "blending in with the natives" is not one of your concerns (which it looks like, since you want to draw on an image) I'd go for Graphics.DrawString. Also, if you'd want printing, you must, since TextRenderer only works on screen (not the printer canvas).

Answer (score 1):

My Personal Experience (I only know these two differences):

DrawString supports Alpha Channel, Anti Aliasing

TextRenderer supports Uniscribe

Answer (score 0):

I'll just throw in some test code:

```
class Form1: Form
{
    private string str = "hello world hello world hello world";
    private int x = 32, yLabel = 0, yDraw = 64, yRenderer = 32;

    public Form1()
    {
        Font = new Font("Times", 16);

        Label label = new Label();
        label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        label.AutoSize = true;
        label.Text = str;
        label.Location = new Point(x, yLabel);
        Controls.Add(label);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        SizeF a;

        // TextRenderer
        a = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, Font);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, str, Font, new Point(x, yRenderer), Color.Pink);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue), x, yRenderer, a.Width, a.Height);

        // DrawString
        e.Graphics.DrawString(str, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), x, yDraw);
        a = e.Graphics.MeasureString(str, Font);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Lime), x, yDraw, a.Width, a.Height);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Bottom line: compared to a simple Label, TextRenderer is more accurate.