# DataGridView: Set AutoSizeRowsMode only for certain rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I am currently creating my own `DataGridViewRow` ([called `DataGridViewMultiRow`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44199977/2505186)), and I want to set only those rows in the DGV to auto-height that are not of the type of my new class.

I have not found a good solution to this yet. My workaround is to fill the multi-row cells with the same merged data that I will draw manually (I will draw in a different way, so this still has its use), ensuring that the auto-height calculates the correct height.
If auto-height is off, then my `PaintRow()` that hooks on `DGV.RowPrePaint event` sets the height directly.

Another (ugly) workaround could be subscribing to a suitable DGV event and calling `AutoResizeRow()` on each DGVR.

Is there a way to apply auto-height settings ony to certain rows?

Comment: Why is doing it in an event ugly?

Comment: @CodingYoshi: because I try to make the use of my new class as easy as possible, but using a DGV event is something I cannot control. it would be in the responsibility of the user to hook a routine to that event.

Comment: how will the rows be filled? data-binding?

Comment: So you want yout special DGVRs to work with your special DGV, right? Creating an event for it is up to you then, no?

Comment: If it works with any DGV how does the Painting work?? As a general question: No, as it is a DGV property it will work for all rows equally. - But: Maybe this is an x-y problem? Why doesn't AutoSizeRowsMode for for rows based on your class??