# How is the LOGFONT quality value set for the TextRenderer

Tags: c#, graphics, drawstring, drawtext, textrenderer

HELP!

I'm working on a C# web app where I am drawing on to a bit map. There are two ways to draw text:
1. Graphics.DrawString
2. TextRenderer.DrawText

According to the internet TextRenderer is the "newer way" but there are times where it looks worse than Graphics.DrawString. I found the following post that had some great information; [Graphics.DrawString vs TextRenderer.DrawText?Which can Deliver Better Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283631/graphics-drawstring-vs-textrenderer-drawtextwhich-can-deliver-better-quality)

The post refers to a LOGFONT quality for the TextRenderer, but I can't figure out how to set the this value. Does anyone know how to set this or have suggestions on best practices for using the TextRenderer?

Code examples would be most helpful.

THANK YOU!