# How can I make that I will be able to drag with the mouse the nodes and replace them change place with other nodes on treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make that I will be able to drag with the mouse the nodes and replace them for example drag root node 0 and move instead root node 4 so now node 0 will be node 4 and 4 will be 0 same for child nodes.

The treeview control code :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class AdvancedTreeView : TreeView
{
    private Bitmap openedIcon, closedIcon;
    private TreeNode _selectedNode;

    public AdvancedTreeView()
    {
        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        ShowLines = false;
        AlternateBackColor = BackColor;
        ArrowColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
    }

    public Color AlternateBackColor { get; set; }
    public Color ArrowColor { get; set; }

    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        // background
        Color backColor = (GetTopNodeIndex(e.Node) & 1) == 0 ? BackColor : AlternateBackColor;
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(backColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Top, ClientSize.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
        }

        // icon
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            Image icon = GetIcon(e.Node.IsExpanded);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(icon, e.Bounds.Left - icon.Width - 3, e.Bounds.Top);
        }

        // text (due to OwnerDrawText mode, indenting of e.Bounds will be correct)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, Font, e.Bounds, ForeColor);

        // indicate selection (if not by backColor):
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds);
    }

    protected override void OnItemDrag(ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Move the dragged node when the left mouse button is used.
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        // Copy the dragged node when the right mouse button is used.
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;
    }

    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the client coordinates of the mouse position.
        Point targetPoint = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        // Select the node at the mouse position.
        this.SelectedNode = this.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);
    }

    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the client coordinates of the drop location.
        Point targetPoint = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        // Retrieve the node at the drop location.
        TreeNode targetNode = this.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);

        // Retrieve the node that was dragged.
        TreeNode draggedNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));

        // Confirm that the node at the drop location is not 
        // the dragged node or a descendant of the dragged node.
        if (!draggedNode.Equals(targetNode) && !ContainsNode(draggedNode, targetNode))
        {
            // If it is a move operation, remove the node from its current 
            // location and add it to the node at the drop location.
            if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
            {
                draggedNode.Remove();
                targetNode.Nodes.Add(draggedNode);
            }

            // If it is a copy operation, clone the dragged node 
            // and add it to the node at the drop location.
            else if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Copy)
            {
                targetNode.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)draggedNode.Clone());
            }

            // Expand the node at the location 
            // to show the dropped node.
            targetNode.Expand();
        }
    }

    private int GetTopNodeIndex(TreeNode node)
    {
        while (node.Parent != null)
            node = node.Parent;

        return Nodes.IndexOf(node);
    }

    // Determine whether one node is a parent 
    // or ancestor of a second node.
    private bool ContainsNode(TreeNode node1, TreeNode node2)
    {
        // Check the parent node of the second node.
        if (node2.Parent == null) return false;
        if (node2.Parent.Equals(node1)) return true;

        // If the parent node is not null or equal to the first node, 
        // call the ContainsNode method recursively using the parent of 
        // the second node.
        return ContainsNode(node1, node2.Parent);
    }

    private Image GetIcon(bool nodeIsExpanded)
    {
        if (openedIcon == null)
            InitIcons();
        return nodeIsExpanded ? openedIcon : closedIcon;
    }

    private void InitIcons()
    {
        openedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        closedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(ArrowColor))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(openedIcon))
                g.FillPolygon(b, new[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(15, 0), new Point(8, 15), });
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(closedIcon))
                g.FillPolygon(b, new[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(15, 8), new Point(0, 15), });
        }
    }
}
```

Edited my question with what I tried so far but is not working either.

Comment: There must be several solutions around. Did you do any research?

Comment: It's working now.  I had ti add in the class constructor the line AllowDrop = true; now the dragging is working.