# How to add a border on the nodes of a treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I work on c# windows form, I have a treeview I have to make a border appear on the nodes and childnodes of the treeview when mouse over.
My problem is that there is no border property for nodes in a treeview, according to my research.
If you know how to do it I will be grateful.
Thanks !!!.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954579/customize-treeview IMO

Comment: Hi, i want a border not a backColor or foreColor. Thanks

Comment: What's the difference? It's all just pixels on a television screen

Comment: (that question is the technique for painting whatever you want; go paint exactly what you want..)

Comment: I want when the mouse is over the node it shows the border of the node.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I need also this

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is a code-related site. Edit your question, show your attempts and code efforts then maybe someone can help. Best luck. Also, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask