# How can I avoid exceptions in Graphics.MeasureString() with bad zero width joiner?

Tags: winforms, gdi+

When I call `Graphics.MeasureString("?\u200d")` I get an ExternalException "A generic error occurred in GDI+".

\u200d is the unicode "zero width joiner", and I guess it is being used incorrectly, but I cannot control the data my users supply, and yet I want to measure it for display.  It also throws the exception when it draws.

I guess I just have to work around this, though it surprises me.

I note that Visual Studio can render the string, perhaps because it is not built on top of GDI+?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TextRenderer.MeasureText()`, and see the excellent (long) answer in [Graphics.DrawString vs TextRenderer.DrawText?Which can Deliver Better Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283631/graphics-drawstring-vs-textrenderer-drawtextwhich-can-deliver-better-quality)